# Module was not compiled for testing @testable import error

Tags: xcode, carthage

The build of ColiseuPlayer using [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage) is failing with **`error: module 'ColiseuPlayer' was not compiled for testing @testable import ColiseuPlayer`**. The build is working if you build it directly from Xcode IDE. Any clue?

You can see the error by checking out [ColiseuPlayer Release-1.0.0 branch](https://github.com/ricardopereira/ColiseuPlayer) and try to build using Carthage like `carthage build --no-skip-current`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong.

Just turn off the "*Run*" flag from the Target:

[image: Target Running flag]

Carthage builds the *Release* configuration with `ENABLE_TESTABILITY=false` which causes tests target build to fail.